# DD4T 2.0 using ViewModels and ModelControllerBase how to add Page Level XPM markup

Tags: dd4t

After reviewing DD4T Github I found that there is a method available in the `DD4T.Mvc.ViewModels.XPM.XpmMarkupService` class that has a method to add Page XPM Markup. However, I couldn't find an HTML helper for that. Additionally the methods in the class are looking for a Tridion Url and an IPage object which is not available while using the `ModelControllerBase` controller. Any ideas on how to render Page XPM Markup while using DD4T 2.0 Model Views?